# DXL matches Method for exact string comparison

Tags: matching, ibm-doors

I am trying to link objects between two modules with a DXL script. In the source object, a string is read. If the string exists in the target module --> Link the objects. Code is working so far. My Problem is, like when my source module has a string "valObject" the matches method is true if my target string contents "valObjectColor". But the matches function should give a false-value.

The heart of the code is below.

Is there any possibility to check for the exact match? I couldn´t find any options in the DXL Reference book.

```
// two nested loops, that go throught every object in both modules and compare given strings
for srcObject in currModule do
{
    if(srcObject."Typ" "" == "Testparameter")
    {
        // save testparameter in variable
        string parameter = srcObject."Object Text" ""

        //iterate throught the targetModule 
        for trgtObject in trgtModule do
        {
                string t = trgtObject."Parameter (Text)"
                if(matches(parameter,t))
                {
                    srcObject -> trgtObject
                    counter ++

                }
        }

    }
}
```

Kind regards
Oguz

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can clarify, but I'm a bit confused why you're using the matches() function:

```
if(matches(parameter,t))
```

matches(a, b) is not used for exact matches but for regular expression matches in your string b. Where string a is your regular expression.

If you want an exact match, you can just perform a simple comparison.

```
if (parameter == t)
```